# How to make HTML img map tag work on Wordpress sidebar

Tags: html, wordpress, image

I'm not a programmer/developer. I tried to put this code on the sidebar of my WordPress website, with the HTML widget. It is working on a page (with the HTML block), but not on the sidebar. I tried with two different themes. Anyone has any idea on how to make it work/a possible alternative?

```
<img src="wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Site2.png" usemap="#image-map" alt="test">

<map name="image-map" id="test-imgmap">
<area target="_blank" alt="test" title="" href="example1" coords="500,398,73,481" shape="rect">
<area target="_blank" alt="test" title="" href="example2" coords="71,493,493,563" shape="rect">
<area target="_blank" alt="test" title="" href="example3" coords="71,570,495,641" shape="rect">
</map>
```